# How to hyperlink all pdf files present in a subfolder to excel?

Tags: excel, vba, file, pdf, hyperlink

I am trying to hyperlink all the fields in column B (picture given below) to the respective content in the folder (picture also provided).

I realized its stupid for me to do it manually and it takes a very long time to do so.
Is there a better way to link them automatically or with more ease?.

I realize that I can do it with help of VBA but I have no clue how to do it.

> This is how my excel column B looks before hyperlinking:

[image: Excel without hyperlinking]

> So this is what I get after **manually** adding the hyperlinks to
>   column B.

[image: The excel after hyperlinking]

> This is the folder(folder name is 2016) which has subfolders (the one in image) and in each of these
>   subfolders there is a pdf file and a word file.

[image: The folder]
I am required to hyperlink the contents in column b (which are not already hyperlinked to the pdf files to their respective subfolders in this folder "2016" (You can see the address bar).

> Here are the pdf and word files inside the subfolders of "2016".

[image: Files inside the subfolder]

So basically you see is that in column B the numbers in the end are in series. I want them hyperlinked to the pdf files inside these subfolders.

If you observe closely , the subfolder have a huge name (including the parenthesis content) , whereas my column B has name of the sub folder excluding the parenthesis part.
So basically its like matching the serial numbers and hyperlinking the pdf file inside the subfolders.

**EDIT:**

> I tried the following by using `=HYPERLINK("\\qatargas.com.qa\doc\Admin\Al_Khor_Community\Alwaha_Club_Admin_Office\Comments & Suggestion Response\2017\"&B1512&" ("&C1512&" "&D1512&")\"&B1512&" ("&C1512&E1510" "&D1512&")"&".pdf";B1512)` on cell e1512.

[image: What I tried]

> I get this error

[image: Error]

Comment: what are the names of the PDF file in the folders?  Same filename name for all?

Comment: Yes , they are the same.Only in pdf format.

Comment: @ashleedawg , can you help me out?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the file before you did the hyperlinks manually?

Comment: @DaDirnbocher, didn't get you.You mean the folders or the excel file?

Comment: I thought you want to have Hyperlinks in column B. If i Interpret the first screenshot right, i see hyperlinks in column b, so i thought the screenshot is the wanted result. In this case, whats the screenshot of the file before doing the hyperlinks?

Comment: @DaDirnbocher , check out the edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new column "C" (or wherever) and enter in (for example) cell `C1210`:

```
=HYPERLINK("file://C:\your_base_path\" & B1210 & "\name_of_pdf_file.pdf","Click to view PDF")
```

Comment: I am really bad at this , can you please tell it in step by step process? Maybe with pictures.

Answer (score 0):

For example in the row 1512: you want to have a hyperlink to a pdf (what is the concrete name of this pdf?) in a path "[...]\qatargas.com.qa\doc\Admin[...]\2016\AKC-CS-17-0124 (QG 3739)". Right?

Then write in cell e1512 the following formula (if the name of pdf is always the same):

```
=HYPERLINK("[...]\qatargas.com.qa\doc\Admin\[...]\2016\"&B1512&" ("&C1512&" "&D1512&")\"&"<nameofyourpdf>";B1512)
```

You have to use your path (i used [...] to drop part of the path) and you have to use the name of your pdf, which is always the same you said.

or if name of the pdf is like the Name of the folder:

```
=HYPERLINK("[...]\qatargas.com.qa\doc\Admin\[...]\2016\"&B1512&" ("&C1512&" "&D1512&")\"&B1512&" ("&C1512&" "&D1512&")"&".pdf";B1512)
```

Comment: then use 
&B1512&" ("&C1512&" "&D1512&")"&".pdf" 
instead of "<nameofyourpdf>"

Comment: Hahah , I am understanding nothing.Sorry.So basically I have to copy paste this whole thing in every cell I click?

Comment: write this formula in cell e1512 (use your correct path, use the additonal info regarding the Name of the pdf) an see what happens.

if ist fine, copy it everywhere you need it.

Comment: Drop the part &E1510

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161105/discussion-between-white-shadow-and-dadirnbocher).